# S3 putCustomQueryParameter to return by LastModified?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

Using the aws cli I can send a `--query` to return only the objects since LastModified:

```
aws s3api list-objects --profile <profile> --bucket <bucket>  --query 'Contents[?LastModified>=`2017-01-19`][]'
```

Works great, returns only objects `>=` the date.

I'm trying to translate this to the Java SDK with something like this:

```
ListObjectsV2Request req = new ListObjectsV2Request();
req.putCustomQueryParameter("LastModified>=`2017-01-19`", null);
```

I've tried a large number of variations on the both the query and parameter strings without any luck- the query always returns all objects. So two questions:

1. Should this work? That is is this something putCustomQueryParameter
   should do?
2. What's the correct syntax if the answer to #1 is 'Yes'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible in the way you envision it.

The cli is actually listing *all* the objects and filtering them locally.  The API (which is what the cli, SDKs, and console all use) doesn't support such a query.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. That was my suspicion after running the cli with `--debug` and watching the GET request/response.